# Send real and complex signal from python to GNU radio. ZMQ Python SUB -> GNU Radio

Tags: python, gnuradio

I've been reading about this. To do this, you should use the ZMQ blocks instead of the [UDP blocks because of data loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240033/reading-signal-from-gnu-radio-udp-sink-from-client-side). Now when using ZMQ I have problems with the received signal, if I create a np array with values 1, 2, 3, etc.. The values that I see in the QT oscilloscope are in the range of 2e-42.  I've been trying to use [PMT](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Polymorphic_Types_(PMTs)) for this but does not seem to work correctly. Another post that seems to work when using bytes is [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69252615/python-zmq-publisher-interfaced-to-gnuradio-sub-message-source-block-issue/69920659#69920659)

My current gnu radio configuration:
[image]

My python code:

```
import zmq
import time
import pmt
import numpy
ctx = zmq.Context()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:4444")
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=numpy.complex64)
a = pmt.to_pmt(a)

while True:
   msg = pmt.serialize_str(a)
   socket.send(msg)
   time.sleep(0.01)
```

The received signal:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  Is `serialize_str` the right method to use? Why not just `serialize`?

Comment: not really a signal processing question, but: You send in PMTs, but interpret them as raw complex numbers. Why are you using PMTs on the transmitting side?

Answer (score 1):

As Marcus Muller said, the problem was that I was using PMT in the transmitting side. This code works:

```
import zmq
import time
import numpy

ctx = zmq.Context()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:1234")

data = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=numpy.complex64)

while True:
   socket.send(data)
   time.sleep(0.01)
```